# Android ViewBinding for Activity requires ViewGroup

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

For my Android app I was trying to implement the ViewBinding Google suggests these days:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

However, there (and in all tutorials) I see this approach for the binding:

```
binding = ResultProfileBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

But that doesn't work when I apply this to my Activity like this:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

[image]

It requires another parameter of the `parent:ViewGroup` which I don't have in my activity. I also can't set it to null like this:

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, null)
```

Since this is a NonNull parameter.

I also tried something someone suggested like this

```
private lateinit var binding2: ViewDataBinding
...
binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
```

but this also failed with the error:

```
NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/databinding/DataBinderMapperImpl;
```

So what am I missing? How can I get the ViewBinding of my Activity?

---- EDIT ----

So to be clear.

1. I added android.useAndroidX=true to the gradle.properties
2. The build.gradle file already contains

   android {
   compileSdk 31

   ```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
   ```
3. The code of the Activity looks like this:

import ...databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
}
```

}

Comment: `binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)` is the right way. What error are you getting?

Comment: I added a screenshot but it says: "No value passed for parameter 'parent'". So is this the wrong call then??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out the issue came from my layout.

The layout file started with a `<merge` tag. I assume the IDE interpreted it as a child layout for me. This didn't seem to give errors for the normal compiling but obviously the view binding was too smart to me.

In any case, when changing it to a normal container like

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
```

it works fine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but adding `android.useAndroidX=true` to `gradle.properties(Project Properties)` it's going to fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks but my gradle.properties file contains already android.useAndroidX=true. Did you change anything else?

Comment: No, But are you sure it's on (Project Properties) because there is two gradle.properties (Global Properties) and (Project Properties), and must be in (Project Properties), I used android arctic fox

Comment: Yes, Arctic Fox and it already was created with that. The gradle.properties (Project Properties) state this. (I dont think I have any other gradle.properties file anyway)